# how to modify a column datatype in mysql so that it saves the previous records in the newly saved format

Tags: mysql

I just need to change the datatype of my column
however, I used the command 
`alter *table_name* modify column *column_name* *datatype*` and it update the datatype but the previously saved result are in the same previous datatype . I want them to be modified too. Any help? And am I clear with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while and I've been bouncing between database engines a lot lately so my syntax may be off, but the general idea will still be valid:

```
SELECT * INTO <table_name>_bak FROM <table_name>;

-- alter your table, leaving nulls in the column

UPDATE <table_name>
SET <column_name> = b.<column_name>
FROM <table_name> t
INNER JOIN <table_name>_bak ON <primary-key-join-clause-here>;

-- disable nulls in your modified column if needed

DROP TABLE <table_name>_bak;
```